# PyQt4: How do I switch from one window to another on a click of a button

Tags: python, pyqt4

So im building an "TeacherPortal" for my python class and the teacher wants us to go to another window from a click of a button specifically using PyQt4. I have looking around but I only found out for PyQt5 and im still very new to GUI's

I have tried creating 2 different classes one for the main window and the other for the second window(they are separate classes) and I put a button with it linked to the other class but it doesn't work

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window,self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("TeahcherPortal")
        self.setGeometry(50,50,800,600)

        self.FirstWindow()

    def FirstWindow(self):
        btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Login",self)
        btn.clicked.connect(SecondPage())
        btn.move(400,300)

        self.show()

class SecondPage(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SecondPage,self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50,50,800,600)



def run():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    Page = SecondPage()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

run()
```

I expected it to go to the other window but that doesn't happen sadly.
But what does happen is I get a error `TypeError: connect() slot argument should be a callable or a signal, not 'SecondPage'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
# PyQt5
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *

# PyQt4
#from PyQt4.QtCore    import *
#from PyQt4.QtGui     import *

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window,self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("TeahcherPortal")
        self.setGeometry(50,50,800,600)

        self.FirstWindow()

    def FirstWindow(self):
        btn = QPushButton("Login", self)
        btn.clicked.connect(self.secondPage)    # - (SecondPage())
        btn.move(400,300)

        self.show()

    def secondPage(self):                       # +++
        self.secondWindow = SecondPage()
        self.secondWindow.show()

class SecondPage(QMainWindow):     
    def __init__(self):
        super(SecondPage,self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("SecondPage")
        self.setGeometry(50,50,800,600)


def run():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    Page = SecondPage()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

run()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply Nick however though when I do run the program I get self  secondWindow() not found

Comment: @aymanalmuti   Comment out the import of PyQt5.
Uncomment the import of PyQt4

Comment: Thanks Again Nick for your time